# How to tag correctly docker image build with gitlab-ci?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am setting up a CI/CD with gitlab.
What I want to do:

- create a dev tagged image
- upload the image to my registry
- deploy the dev image on the dev server
- create the prod tagged image
- upload the image to my registry
- deploy the prod image

The application is an application developed in React based on an API.
The only difference between the image tagged dev and the one of prod is the url of the api.
(The dev react application must point to the dev api and the prod one to the prod api)

For the moment, I've done that:

```yaml
stages:
  - docker-build
  - deploy
  - deploy-prod

docker-build:
  stage: docker-build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03.8-dind
  script:
    - sudo docker login -u registry_user -p 'MYPASWORD' https://XXXXX.com
    - sudo docker build -t XXXXX.com/myapp .
    - sudo docker push XXXXX.com/myapp
    - sudo docker rmi XXXXX.com/myapp
    - sudo docker image prune -f
    - sudo docker logout
  tags:
    - build

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  before_script:
    - echo "deploying app"
  script:
    - sudo ln -s docker-compose.yml.dev docker-compose.yml
    - sudo docker login -u registry_user -p 'MYPASSWORD' https://XXXXX.com
    - sudo docker-compose pull
    - sudo docker logout
    - sudo docker-compose up -d
  tags:
    - dev

deploy-prd1:
  stage: deploy-prod
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  before_script:
    - echo "deploying app"
  script:
    - sudo ln -s docker-compose.yml.prd docker-compose.yml
    - sudo docker login -u registry_user -p 'MYPASSWORD' https://XXXX.com
    - sudo docker-compose pull
    - sudo docker logout
    - sudo docker-compose up -d
  tags:
    - prodg
  when: manual

deploy-prd2:
  stage: deploy-prod
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  before_script:
    - echo "deploying app"
  script:
    - sudo ln -s docker-compose.yml.prd docker-compose.yml
    - sudo docker login -u registry_user -p 'MYPASSWORD' https://XXXX.com
    - sudo docker-compose pull
    - sudo docker logout
    - sudo docker-compose up -d
  tags:
    - prods
  when: manual
```

In my docker-compose.yml.prd and docker-compose.yml.dev, I have:
`image: XXXXX.com/myapp:prod` or `image: XXXXX.com/myapp:dev`

The url of the api is defined in a .js file as a constant.
`const url="api-XXXX.com"`

What is the best way to build 2 different images with 2 different urls?

Comment: The use of `sudo` all over the place is a big red flag FYI. Did it not work without it??

Comment: No but it's a very limited sudo (only the commands in the gitlab-ci.yml file). But yes it's probably better to add the user gitlab-runner in docker group ....

Comment: Also, more directly to your question, if the only difference between the two images is the URL, do you really need two images? Or would it make more sense to use the URL as an environment variable at runtime and only publish a single image?

Comment: You mean add `environment` with the url in my docker-compose.yml.prd and docker-compose.yml.dev? and get this URL with `process.env.url` in my react app ?

Comment: Yes. Whether this will work or not depends on your react app. For static sites or even frameworks like next.js, public environment variables need to be set at *build* time. But if your app allows variables to be set at runtime, I think that would be the simplest path forward.

Comment: I think it should work. I'm going to test it anyway. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I can pass the ENV var before use npm run build but not after. So how I can have 1 image if the build must be different between the dev and thr prod ?

Comment: You should be passing the environment variable in at runtime when you run the docker image, it's not required to be passed in when you build the image. Worst case scenario, you define it as a variable with a placeholder in the docker image, then replace the variable value during runtime. Either way, you should use the same docker image for prod that you do for dev, that's a key tenant of using docker :)

Comment: I think the limitation is not from docker but from react.
What I mean is that I do have my environment variable within my container.
But this variable is ignored. I have the impression that when I do the build of my react application it hard replaces the URL value in the bundle.js.